# Footnote creates unwanted space

Tags: spacing, footnotes, reledmac

[image]In an interlinear translation (Yiddish left side - German right side) I have footnotes, which unfortunately mess up the line spacing.  What can I do to make this distance go away?

> compiling with xelatex

```
    % arara: xelatex

   \documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}
   \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

   \usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}



   \usepackage{scrpage2}
   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
   \clearscrheadfoot

   \ihead{\headmark}
   %\automark[chapter]{chapter}
   %\automark*[section]{}

   \ohead{\pagemark}
   \setheadsepline{0.4pt}
   \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}

   %Formatierung der Kopfzeilen:
   \addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}


   \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} %Schrift in Überschriften, Inhaltsverzeichnis

   \clubpenalty=10000
   \widowpenalty=10000

   \usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
   \usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
   \usepackage{reledpar}



   %%%\Xendnumberonlyfirstinline

   \Xendbeforepagenumber{S.\,}
   \Xendafterpagenumber{:\,}
   \Xendlineprefixsingle{Z.\,}

   \setgoalfraction{0.85}


   \lineation{section}
   \linenummargin{left}%%right für Zeilennummern rechts
   %\setRlineflag{}



   \linenumincrement*{5}
   \firstlinenum*{0} %Zahl hochsetzen, um Titelei unnummeriert zu haben

   \maxchunks{10000}

   \usepackage{color}
   \usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}%%times RAUS





   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
   \usepackage{libertine}
   \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}%Linux Libertine O %%EzraSIL hat keine kursiva

   \setmainlanguage{german}
   \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
   \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{EzraSIL}



   \setmainlanguage{german}
   \setotherlanguage{hebrew}


   \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}



   \newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

   \newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
   }

   \newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

   \newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
   {\textsc{#1}} \einzug
   }

   \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}



   \begin{document}



   \begin{pages}
   \begin{Leftside}
    \setRTL
    \beginnumbering


\pstart {\texthebrew{\speaker{שלמה.}
איהר\RTLfootnote[3]{האָן איהר}
 נעבעיונגע מער לעססע אייך אַהן {לֵיצים}  דוֹא, דען קענט איהר אייך דערווייל לושטיג מאַכע, ביס מיר געססע האָן. {(}{אַב}{)} {(}{אונטער ווילדעם  געפאָלטער אַללע אַב ביס אויף גומפלכען}{)}
}}

\pend

        \endnumbering
   \end{Leftside}


   \begin{Rightside}

   \beginnumbering


  \pstart \speakerd{Schlaumeche.} Ihr\footnote[3]{hai} \textit{Nebenjungen},wir lassen euch einen  leisen Ton da, dann könnt ihr derweil lustig sein, bis wir gegessen haben. \textit{(Ab.)} \textit{(Unter wildem Gepolter alle ab bis auf Gumpelchen.)} \pend

   \endnumbering

   \end{Rightside}
   \end{pages}
   \Pages



   \end{document}
```

Comment: you should use \Afootnote specific to reledmac/reledpar.

Comment: @Maïeul: thank you. but this doesn't work either (then I have just no footnote).

Comment: sorry, it was \footnoteA (\Afootnote is for critical footnote)

Comment: Ok, this one I tried before; but it is not what I need. The problem is this: First I want to number my footnotes by myself. Second: The left page is right-aligned (Hebrew), therefore the footnote must start on the right at the bottom  of the left page, while on the right page it should start on the left.

Comment: all thas thing could be set. Unfortunatly, now I have no time (RTL scripting is complex). I will try this week. Don't hesitate to send me an email next mondy if you hae no answer.

Comment: thank you! I'm looking forward your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that footnote defined by bidi are not compatible with footnote defined by reledmac and by the way reledmac numbers/split the lines.

However, reledmac as the tool to get your goal.

## General rule to set language in parallel typesetting

You must wrap side with a specific language with language environment, and not changing language environment inside.

So

```
 \begin{hebrew}
   \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering

    \pstart \speaker{שלמה.}
    איהר\footnote[3]{האָן איהר}
    נעבעיונגע מער לעססע אייך אַהן {לֵיצים}  דוֹא, דען קענט איהר אייך דערווייל לושטיג מאַכע, ביס מיר געססע האָן. {(}{אַב}{)} {(}{אונטער ווילדעם  געפאָלטער אַללע אַב ביס אויף גומפלכען}{)}

    \pend

    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
\end{hebrew}
```

## Using reledmac footnote

You must use reledmac familiar footnote (`\footnoteA`, `\footnoteB`, etc) inside reledmac part of texts. However, older version of reledmac didn't allow to manually numbering familiar footnote. The version 2.28.0, that I have just send on CTAN, allows it. So you should wait few day and upgrade your TeXLive/Miktex packages.

So

```
\pstart \speaker{שלמה.}
איהר\footnoteA[3]{האָן איהר}
נעבעיונגע מער לעססע אייך אַהן {לֵיצים}  דוֹא, דען קענט איהר אייך דערווייל לושטיג מאַכע, ביס מיר געססע האָן. {(}{אַב}{)} {(}{אונטער ווילדעם  געפאָלטער אַללע אַב ביס אויף גומפלכען}{)}


\pend
```

## footnote apparence setting

In order to have right font family in footnoteA, for hebrew text, you must automatically wrap footnote insided hebrew command, using `\wrapcontentX` reledmac hook. 
In order to have footnote rule right aligned for series A, you must redefine it.

So

```
\wrapcontentx[a]{\texthebrew}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoterulea}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother
```

## General code

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot

\ihead{\headmark}
%\automark[chapter]{chapter}
%\automark*[section]{}

\ohead{\pagemark}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}

%Formatierung der Kopfzeilen:
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} %Schrift in Überschriften, Inhaltsverzeichnis

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


%%%\Xendnumberonlyfirstinline

\Xendbeforepagenumber{S.\,}
\Xendafterpagenumber{:\,}
\Xendlineprefixsingle{Z.\,}

\setgoalfraction{0.85}

\lineation{section}
\linenummargin{left}%%right für Zeilennummern rechts
%\setRlineflag{}

\linenumincrement*{5}
\firstlinenum*{0} %Zahl hochsetzen, um Titelei unnummeriert zu haben

\maxchunks{10000}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}%%times RAUS





\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}%Linux Libertine O %%EzraSIL hat keine kursiva

\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{EzraSIL}


\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\wrapcontentX[A]{\texthebrew}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoteruleA}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{pages}
\begin{hebrew}
 \begin{Leftside}
   \beginnumbering

   \pstart \speaker{שלמה.}
   איהר\footnoteA[3]{האָן איהר}
   נעבעיונגע מער לעססע אייך אַהן {לֵיצים}  דוֹא, דען קענט איהר אייך דערווייל לושטיג מאַכע, ביס מיר געססע האָן. {(}{אַב}{)} {(}{אונטער ווילדעם  געפאָלטער אַללע אַב ביס אויף גומפלכען}{)}

   \pend

   \endnumbering
 \end{Leftside}
\end{hebrew}

\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart \speakerd{Schlaumeche.} Ihr\footnoteB[3]{hai} \textit{Nebenjungen},wir lassen euch einen  leisen Ton da, dann könnt ihr derweil lustig sein, bis wir gegessen haben. \textit{(Ab.)} \textit{(Unter wildem Gepolter alle ab bis auf Gumpelchen.)} \pend

\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I am afraid that I still have problems in the output. It gives me an empty footnote and a "3]" instead of an uppercase number. Is it just me? Is it my TeX-distribution?

Comment: As explained in the answer, you must have the newest version of reledmac (2.28.0), that I have just send on CTAN.

So wait few day, and upgrade your TeX-distribution

Comment: Any ideas how I can manage this footnotes numbers appear not in superscript?

Comment: please open a new question

Comment: ok, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477099/37930