# style of reledmac footnote (superscript, hanging indent)

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

I'm using reledmac footnotes (\footnoteA, \footnoteB) but my poublisher wants the footnote numbers not appear in superscript? Also they want a hanging indent.

```
    \wrapcontentx[a]{\texthebrew}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoterulea}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother
```

Any ideas how this might work?

Example of the complex manuscript:

```
    % arara: xelatex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions
  {
    fontsize=10pt,
    paper=24cm:16cm,
    pagesize=pdftex,
    DIV=calc,
  } %%%weitere Einstellungen des Seitenspiegels



  \usepackage{leading}
  \leading{12pt}




  \usepackage[%%%text={12cm,17.8cm},
paperwidth=16cm,
paperheight=23cm,
    top=1.6cm,%%%3.45cm,
    bottom=3.45cm,%%%8.04cm,
    inner=2.7cm,%%%4.15cm,
    outer=2.3cm,%%%4.85cm,
   %%% marginparsep=7mm,
    %%%marginparwidth=48mm,
  ]{geometry} %%% Seitenlayout 

%%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%%\usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}


%%\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}

%Formatierung der Kopfzeilen:
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}


\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} %Schrift in Überschriften, Inhaltsverzeichnis

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epigraph} %für Zitate

\usepackage{tipa} %%für IPA-Zeichen
%%%\Xendnumberonlyfirstinline

\Xendbeforepagenumber{S.\,}
\Xendafterpagenumber{:\,}
\Xendlineprefixsingle{Z.\,}

\setgoalfraction{0.85}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\lineation{section}
\linenummargin{left}%%right für Zeilennummern rechts
%\setRlineflag{}


\usepackage{pdflscape} %%Querformatiges Bild

\linenumincrement*{5}
\firstlinenum*{0} %Zahl hochsetzen, um Titelei unnummeriert zu haben

\maxchunks{10000}

% Hurenkinder und Schusterjungen verhindern
\clubpenalty10000
\widowpenalty10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}%%times RAUS
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}%Linux Libertine O %%EzraSIL hat keine kursiva

\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote %idee wegen fußnotenabstand

\setmainlanguage{german} 
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=0.8]{EzraSIL} %Keter YG %%hebräische schrift auf 9ppt verkleinert




%addsubsection definiert
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\addsubsec{\secdef\@addsubsec\@saddsubsec}
\newcommand*{\@addsubsec}{}
\def\@addsubsec[#1]#2{\subsection*{#2}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
  \if@twoside\ifx\@mkboth\markboth\markright{#1}\fi\fi
}
\newcommand*{\@saddsubsec}[1]{\subsection*{#1}\@mkboth{}{}}
\makeatother








%%Header Neu
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  oddpage,
  rightmargin,
  height=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight,
  contents={\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}%
    \vfill%
    \hspace{\marginparsep}\pagemark\hfill%
  }
]{pagenumber.odd}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  evenpage,
  leftmargin,
  height=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight,
  contents={\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}%
    \vfill% 
    \hfill\pagemark\hspace{\marginparsep}%
  }
]{pagenumber.even}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber.odd, pagenumber.even}

\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}

%\usepackage{scrpage2}
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\clearscrheadfoot

%\chead{\headmark}
%\automark[chapter]{chapter}
%\automark*[section]{}

%\ohead{\pagemark}

%HAMSA für Schirm
\newcommand{\dotplus}{\includegraphics[width=0.07in]{images/trefoil.png}}




\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
%\setotherlanguage{arabic}

%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.3]{Scheherazade}
%\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}



\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}


\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}



\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,language=ngerman]{biblatex} \bibliography{LitGrobsdorfEdition}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\,}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}


\deffootnote[\normalparindent]
            {0em}
            {\normalparindent}
            {\thefootnotemark\ \,}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}

\usepackage{bidi}\autofootnoterule

\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\ \,} %%neu aus Ricarda-Diss



\wrapcontentX[A]{\texthebrew}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoteruleA}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother

 %%FN alt  \renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}


\newcommand{\rot}[1]{{\color{red} #1}}
\newcommand{\hai}[1]{\textsf{#1}} %für Text in Arial
\newcommand{\qu}[1]{»#1«} % >> <<
\newcommand{\quji}[1]{»#1«} %jiddische (dt.) Anführungszeichen
\newcommand{\quein}[1]{›#1‹} %einfache > <
\newcommand{\quf}[1]{\frqq#1\flqq} %franz. Anführungszeichen
\newcommand{\qufs}[1]{\frq#1\flq} %einfache franz. Anführungszeichen
\newcommand{\sem}[1]{›#1‹} %‘#1' 69er anführungszeichen Bedeutungsangabe

\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}



\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside} \begin{hebrew}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{חתן.}
{גם אַתה}.
 אייער פראַה און קינדער זעללע לעבע!}}
 \pend


\pstart {\RL{\speaker{יוקב.}
 מייא איהר לייט, מער זעללט נאך אַביסכה וואַרטע מיט דעם עססע איך ווילל ערשט
 דען שופט רופע לאָססע, דער זאָלל
אַהך מיט עססע. האַלט אַביסכה אין! שמואל, רוהף אמויהל דען
{צאָן}!\footnoteA[4]{\RL{צאָן ווירד געוואֶהנליך דורך שאַאף איבערזעטצט (נאַך מענדעלזאָהן: קליינעס פֿיה). שאַף אין
י\~{{\RL{}}}ודיש-דייטשער
 מונדאַרט.
 שויף. אֶהנעלנד מיט שופט.
 דאַהער וואַהרשיינליך דיע אַנאַלאָגישע בענעננונג דער שולצען בייא דען לאנדיודען. צאָן. איים פלוראַל אַבער צאָננע. צאָננעכער נעננען זיע דען שאַאפֿהירטען.
}}
}}\pend



     \endnumbering
\end{hebrew}\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering



\pstart \speakerd{Bräutigam.} Auch du, Eure Frau und Kinder sollen leben! \pend 

\pstart \speakerd{Jakob.} Mei ihr Leute, man sollte noch ein bisschen warten mit dem Essen, ich will erst den Schultheiß rufen lassen, der soll auch mitessen. Haltet ein bisschen ein! Samuel, ruf einmal den \textit{Son} [Schultheiß].\footnoteB[4]{\textit{Son} wird gewöhnlich durch Schaf übersetzt (nach Mendelsohn: kleines Fieh). Schaf in jüdisch-deutscher Mundart: \textit{Schauf}/\textit{Schoif} ähnelnd mit \textit{Schuft}. Daher wahrscheinlich die analogische Benennung der Schulzen bei den Landjuden. \textit{Son}. Im Plural aber \textit{Sonne}. \textit{Sonnecher} nennen sie den Schafhirten.} \pend
\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: As always: please provide a compilable example.

Comment: Sorry, now it's a full (but messy) MWE

Comment: this example is not minimal...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the footnote mark, there is not yet any reledmac direct hook. You must redefine the commands (as explained on § 6.5.2 of the reldmac handbook).

So

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bodyfootmarkA}{%
  \hbox{\normalfont\@nameuse{@thefnmarkA}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\footfootmarkA}{%
  \@nameuse{@thefnmarkA}%
}
\renewcommand*{\bodyfootmarkB}{%
  \hbox{\normalfont\@nameuse{@thefnmarkB}}%
}
\renewcommand*{\footfootmarkB}{%
  \@nameuse{@thefnmarkB}%
}
\makeatother
```

For the hangindent, as explained in § 7.7 of the handbook, you must use  `hangindentX`. For example

```
\hangindentX{2em}
```

However, there is a bug for RTL content. The bug has been corrected on reledmac 2.31.1.

Comment: just one little thing: the hangindent with the hebrew text seems to make problems: the indent is on the wrong side.

Comment: should I make a new question for this problem with the hebrew footnote?

Comment: now, I have already opened a question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477135/hangeindent-and-rtl-text/477138#477138

Comment: after that, i would have to implemnet a solution on reledmac, so, please open a issue on github instead  (with a really minimal example)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do this an github – also, my examples are bad :(

Comment: Do you know, in general, how to get a package handbook? I explained it on the top of the package handbook (that you can find using texdoc reledmac on a terminal, or on the ctan.

By the way, for github issues, it is explained on https://github.com/maieul/ledmac

Comment: I have just send on the CTAN a version 2.31.1 of reledmac, which fix the bug with \Xhangindent and \hangindentX for RTL texts.